# How to store TextField Values even after the software closes or power loss in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, blend

I have many TextFields in my WPF App in C#. Where user can input information and when save button is pressed, the values are stored in SQL Database. I want to keep the values until save button is pressed or user clear the values. How can i do that?

Comment: save them in a text file or sqllite database

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Caching TextFields for application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789217/caching-textfields-for-application)

Comment: You can use app settings.